# "mprof run <executable>": What does each output column represent?

Tags: python, memory-profiling

I ran `mprof run some-executable` and it produced a `*.dat` file.

What does each column of the `*.dat` file signify?

```
vikas@some-host$ cat mprofile_20150224012014.dat              
CMDLINE python ../asl
MEM 0.332031 1424769614.8950
MEM 7.593750 1424769614.9954
MEM 8.816406 1424769615.0957
MEM 8.816406 1424769615.1960
```

What do those 1st/2nd/3rd columns represent?

**[EDIT]:**
Also I am not able to run mprof run --python.
Here is the error(importerror) I am getting.... looks like it is not able to get the definition of config

(virtualenv)vikas@host:$ ./mprof run --python ../myfile.py

mprof: Sampling memory every 0.1s

running as a Python program...

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/runpy.py", line 122, in _run_module_as_main
"__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
File "/usr/lib64/python2.6/runpy.py", line 34, in _run_code
exec code in run_globals
File "/home/vikask/memory_profiler-0.32/memory_profiler.py", line 853, in <module>
execfile(__file__, ns, ns)
File "../myfile.py", line 19, in <module>
from bsite import models, security
File "/home/vikas/bsite/models.py", line 12, in <module>
from bsite import config
ImportError: cannot import name config
```

Answer (score 5):

1st column: "MEM" is just a label.

2nd column: RSS (resident set size) in megabytes. So your process ended up using 8.8 MB.

3rd column: Unix time stamp:

```
>>> import time
>>> print(time.ctime(1424769615.1960))
Tue Feb 24 01:20:15 2015
```

It looks like `mprof` just logs the process size over time. If you want more specific details about the internals of your program (line-by-line) it looks like you can use `mprof run --python file.py` to get that information (you also need to decorate your functions with `@profile`, see the [Usage section in the documentation](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler)).

**Edit**: In response to the ImportError & traceback you posted: You are getting that error because you're running the file as `"../myfile.py"`. Since you're outside of the `bsite` directory it can't find the `config.py` file.

You need to run the program like this:

```
 $ cd /home/vikas/bsite/
 $ /home/vikask/memory_profiler-0.32/mprof run --python myfile.py
```

This way you're in the correct directory for the `import` to work.

Another way to get it to work is to [build your project as a python package](https://packaging.python.org/en/latest/index.html). When you do this your files can be properly imported from anywhere. This is a little complicated to get set up, but it's a pretty good idea.

The other more hacky option is to modify `PYTHONPATH` or `sys.path` to get the imports to work. For example like this:

```
$ cd /home/vikask/memory_profiler-0.32/
$ PYTHONPATH=/home/vikas/bsite/ ./mprof run --python ../myfile.py
```

Finally, it looks like you're running the `mprof` command directly from the memory_profiler source. You can install the package by doing "`python setup.py install`" in that directory (or by using `pip install memory_profiler`). Then you should have the `mprof` command on your PATH and can run it from any directory.

Comment: "mprof run --python file.py" works for stand alone(self contained) file. But I want to use this in my project where a file is heavily dependent on many other files(for imports...). Under those situations running {mprof run --python file.py} becomes very tricky. It starts giving lot of {ImportErrors}

Comment: Alright, what kind of ImportErrors? What import is failing? I don't see anything that would make mprof more difficult to use with a large project. If you can run a program normally, it should also work under mprof.

Comment: How can a run a program(in this case it is "myfile.py"). this file doesn't have any main.... it is being called by lot of other python files. So how can I run only this file as standalone.... I have pasted the ImportError I am getting   as an answer... see above

Answer (score 1):

If anyone comes here with a problem that `mprof` doesnt work on Windows(like me), do the following:

After installation of `memory_profiler`

1) go to your Python\Scripts folder, change your file `mprof` type to `mprof.py`

2) in the same folder as in 1), create new file `mprof`, add there following text

```
@echo off

python "%~dpn0.py" %*
```

3)Save the file and change its type to `mprof.bat`

Now everything should work.
Good luck!